# C++ Custom Action returns empty string

Tags: c++, wix

We are having problem with a deferred custom action in c++.  We simply want the value for a customactiondata property 'apacheconfpath' which has a dummy value of test at the moment.

Here is a our c++ custom action:

```
 UINT __stdcall AppendToApacheConfigFile(MSIHANDLE hInstall)
{
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;
    UINT er = ERROR_SUCCESS;
    TCHAR sWord[100];

    hr = WcaInitialize(hInstall, "AppendToApacheConfigFile");
    ExitOnFailure(hr, "Failed to initialize");

    TCHAR szActionData[MAX_PATH] = {0}; 
    DWORD dActionDataLen = MAX_PATH; 
    MsiGetProperty (hInstall, TEXT("apacheconfpath"), TEXT(""), &dActionDataLen);

    StringCbPrintf(sWord, 100, TEXT("%d"), dActionDataLen);
    WcaLog(LOGMSG_STANDARD, "dActionDataLen = %s", sWord);

    if (dActionDataLen > 0)
    {   
      ++dActionDataLen;
      StringCbPrintf(sWord, 100, TEXT("%d"), dActionDataLen);
      WcaLog(LOGMSG_STANDARD, "dActionDataLen(2) = %s", sWord);
      MsiGetProperty (hInstall, TEXT("apacheconfpath"), szActionData, &dActionDataLen);         
      WcaLog(LOGMSG_STANDARD, "szActionData = %s", szActionData);
      StringCbPrintf(sWord, 100, TEXT("%d"), dActionDataLen);
      WcaLog(LOGMSG_STANDARD, "dActionDataLen(3) = %s", sWord);

     //Do something with the value
    }

    LExit:
      er = SUCCEEDED(hr) ? ERROR_SUCCESS : ERROR_INSTALL_FAILURE;
      return WcaFinalize(er);
}
```

The property is set here in our wix installer:

```
<CustomAction Id="AppendToApacheConfigFile_Cmd" Property="AppendToApacheConfigFile" Value="/apacheconfpath=test;" />
<CustomAction Id="AppendToApacheConfigFile" BinaryKey="CustomActionDll" DllEntry="AppendToApacheConfigFile" Execute="deferred" />

<InstallExecuteSequence>
      <Custom Action="AppendToApacheConfigFile_Cmd" Before="AppendToApacheConfigFile"><![CDATA[IIS_SELECTED <> 1]]></Custom>
      <Custom Action="AppendToApacheConfigFile" After="DeployPhpRuntime"><![CDATA[IIS_SELECTED <> 1]]></Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

I have added lots of logging to try to see what is happening.  It would appear that the property is never read as the dword value is always 0 and the data is always empty.  We never get past the first read.

According to the log the value has been set

```
MSI (s) (80:C4) [20:59:30:210]: Executing op: CustomActionSchedule(Action=AppendToApacheConfigFile,ActionType=1025,Source=BinaryData,Target=AppendToApacheConfigFile,CustomActionData=/apacheconfpath=test;)
```

Any information would be most welcome

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the deferred custom action requests the data it ask for it via the well known identifier `CustomActionData`. You can see that name referenced in the log file at the end of this line:

```
MSI (s) (80:C4) [20:59:30:210]: Executing op: CustomActionSchedule(Action=AppendToApacheConfigFile,ActionType=1025,Source=BinaryData,Target=AppendToApacheConfigFile,CustomActionData=/apacheconfpath=test;)
```

To access the data, you'd change your `MsiGetProperty` call to look more like:

```
MsiGetProperty(hInstall, TEXT("CustomActionData"), TEXT(""), &dActionDataLen);
```

Note: Since you are already using wcautil, I highly recommend using `WcaGetProperty()` instead of `MsiGetProperty()`. You'll want to check the return code from `WcaGetProperty()` and in doing so your custom action will correctly handle user cancels. Otherwise, your custom action could swallow the user's attempt to cancel the install.

Comment: Thanks.  The suggestion to use WCaGetProperty() has got me a little further forward.

Comment: hr = WcaGetProperty (L"CustomActionData", &pszActionData);

Comment: I now get the first character of CustomActionData

Comment: My log output now shows:AppendToApacheConfigFile:  pszActionData = /

Comment: `pszActionData` will be a Unicode string. You'll want to change your format from `%s` (which expects ANSI string when compiling your code as ANSI) to `%ls` (which **always** expects Unicode string).