# Wix C++ Custom Action for Creating File

Tags: c#, visual-c++, wix

Previously I had written a C# Custom Action that was supposed to get the `Values` of `Properties` passed to the installer and create some config file. Since the C# Custom action was done, my installer depends upon `.Net` too. The only way to remove the `.Net` dependency is to write the Custom Action in `C++`.

My previous C# code which I'm trying to convert to C++ is below:

```
session.Log("Entering WriteFileToDisk");
string ipAddress = session["IPADDRESS"];
string productCode = session["ProductCode"];
string config_path = "C:\\SomeFolderToInstall\\";
string compression = session["COMPRESSION"];
string ssl = session["SSL"];
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(compression))
{
      compression = "True"; //default true
}
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ssl))
{
      ssl = "False"; //default false
}
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ipAddress))
{
      ipAddress = "127.0.0.1";
}
string temp = @"
{{
      ""logpoint_ip"" : ""{0}"",
      ""compression"" : ""{1}"",
      ""ssl"": ""{2}"" 
}}";
string filePath = "C:\\SomeFolderToInstall\\lpa.config";
System.IO.FileInfo file = new System.IO.FileInfo(filePath);
file.Directory.Create(); // If the directory already exists, this method does nothing.
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(file.FullName, config);
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(config_path + "productcode.txt", productCode);
session.Log("Confile file is written");
session.Log("Product Code file is written");
return ActionResult.Success;
```

The Visual C++ code for above C# code is given below:

```
#include "stdafx.h"    
UINT __stdcall WriteFileToDisk(MSIHANDLE hInstall)
{
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;
    UINT er = ERROR_SUCCESS;

    hr = WcaInitialize(hInstall, "WriteFileToDisk");
    ExitOnFailure(hr, "Failed to initialize");

    LPWSTR ip = NULL;
    hr = WcaGetProperty(L"IPADDRESS",&ip);
    ExitOnFailure(hr, "Failure in IPADDRESS");

    if(ip == L"" || ip == NULL)
    {
        ip = L"127.0.0.1";
    }
    WcaLog(LOGMSG_STANDARD, (PCSTR)ip);
    LPWSTR ssl = NULL;
    hr = WcaGetProperty(L"SSL",&ssl);
    ExitOnFailure(hr, "Failure in SSL");

    if(ssl == L"" || ssl == NULL)
    {
        ssl = L"False";
    }
    LPWSTR comp = NULL;
    hr = WcaGetProperty(L"COMPRESSION",&comp);
    ExitOnFailure(hr, "Failure in COMPRESSION");

    if(comp == L"" || comp == NULL)
    {
        comp = L"True";
    }

    WcaLog(LOGMSG_STANDARD, "Got the Parameters");
    char buffer[150];
    sprintf(buffer, "{\n\"ipaddress\": \"%s\",\n\"ssl\": \"%s\",\n\"compression\":\"%s\"\n}",ip,ssl,comp);
    WcaLog(LOGMSG_STANDARD, "Config Generated is : ");
    WcaLog(LOGMSG_STANDARD, buffer);

    HANDLE hFile;
    hFile = CreateFile(L"C://LogPointAgent//some_config.config",                // name of the write
                       GENERIC_WRITE,          // open for writing
                       0,                      // do not share
                       NULL,                   // default security
                       CREATE_NEW,             // create new file only
                       FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,  // normal file
                       NULL);

     if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) 
    { 
        WcaLog(LOGMSG_STANDARD, "Invalid Handle for Config File");
        ExitFunction();
    }
     BOOL bErrorFlag;
     DWORD dwBytesToWrite = (DWORD)strlen(buffer);
     DWORD dwBytesWritten = 0;
     bErrorFlag = WriteFile( 
                    hFile,           // open file handle
                    buffer,      // start of data to write
                    dwBytesToWrite,  // number of bytes to write
                    &dwBytesWritten, // number of bytes that were written
                    NULL);            // no overlapped structure


     if (FALSE == bErrorFlag)
    {
        WcaLog(LOGMSG_STANDARD, "Terminal failure: Unable to write to file.\n");
    }
    else
    {
        if (dwBytesWritten != dwBytesToWrite)
        {
            // This is an error because a synchronous write that results in
            // success (WriteFile returns TRUE) should write all data as
            // requested. This would not necessarily be the case for
            // asynchronous writes.
            WcaLog(LOGMSG_STANDARD, "Error: dwBytesWritten != dwBytesToWrite\n");
        }
        else
        {
            WcaLog(LOGMSG_STANDARD, "Wrote Config file Successfully");
        }
    }

      CloseHandle(hFile);
LExit:
    er = SUCCEEDED(hr) ? ERROR_SUCCESS : ERROR_INSTALL_FAILURE;
    return WcaFinalize(er);
}

// DllMain - Initialize and cleanup WiX custom action utils.
extern "C" BOOL WINAPI DllMain(
    __in HINSTANCE hInst,
    __in ULONG ulReason,
    __in LPVOID
    )
{
    switch(ulReason)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        WcaGlobalInitialize(hInst);
        break;

    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        WcaGlobalFinalize();
        break;
    }

    return TRUE;
}
```

Below is the `Wix` file code that is used to call the function `WriteFileToDisk` from the dll generated by C++ custom action:

```
<Binary Id="SetupCA"  SourceFile="..\WixCustomActionCPP\bin\Release\WixCustomActionCPP.dll"/>
<CustomAction Id="WRITEFILETODISK" Execute="immediate" BinaryKey="SetupCA" DllEntry="WriteFileToDisk" />
<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action="WRITEFILETODISK" Before="InstallFinalize">NOT Installed</Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

When installer is installed using command `msiexec /i installer.msi /l*v out.txt IPADDRESS="192.168.2.208"` ,it is supposed to generate config as:

```
{
"ip":"192.168.2.208",
"ssl":"False",
"compression":"True"
}
```

but what it generates now is:

```
{
"ipaddress": "1",
"ssl": "",
"compression":""
}
```

What is wrong in the C++ code here? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this answer:

[C++ Custom Action returns empty string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16135732/c-custom-action-returns-empty-string)

It looks like you're using Ansi formatting to get a Unicode string.

Also you seem to be mixing up Unicode and Ansi in sprintf too. That code should use WCHAR and other Unicode constructs. Forget Ansi, forget char and sprintf (use wsprintf for Unicode) and I assume the VC++ build is Unicode anyway.

Comment: Phil, using `%ls` did wrote the config correctly and was logged too, but it wasn't written in config file. The config file was blank.

Comment: Thanks Phil. After your edit, I did modified the code and wrote it in order to support the Unicode. The code now works fine when changed to support the Unicode.