# Getting CustomActionData from C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, wix

I have a `Wix` file where I am creating a `Deferred Custom Action`. I have written a `C#` program, which is, for now, looping over the `CustomActionData` and printing the `Key` and `Values`. Consider the snippet given below:

```
<Binary Id="myAction" SourceFile="..\Type51CA\bin\Release\Type51CA.CA.dll" />
<CustomAction Id="CustomAction1" Property="CustomAction2" Value="SomePropertyOne=[INSTALLFOLDER];SomePropertyTwo=[IPADDRESS];" />
  <CustomAction Id="CustomAction2" BinaryKey="myAction" DllEntry="MyCustomAction" Execute="deferred" Return="check" HideTarget="no" />
<InstallExecuteSequence>
   <Custom Action="CustomAction1" Before="CustomAction2" />
   <Custom Action="CustomAction2" Before="InstallFinalize" />
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

I am setting the `SomePropertyOne` and `SomePropertyTwo` in CA `Id="CustomAction1"`.

The following C# code can iterate over `CustomActionData`

```
session.Log("Begin MyCustomAction");
CustomActionData datas = session.CustomActionData;
foreach (KeyValuePair<String, String> data in datas)
{
   session.Log(String.Format("Key = {0} Value = {1}\n", data.Key, data.Value));
}
```

Since I want to remove the dependency of .Net, I want to write the equivalent C# code in C++; using `WcaGetProperty(L"CustomActionData",&caData)` didn't give me any result. In C++, how can I get the required `value` of a corresponding `Key` from `CustomActionData`?

Answer (score 0):

CustomActionData can be as simple as you want or as complicated as you want. My favorite is [JSON](http://blog.iswix.com/2011/10/beam-me-up-using-json-to-serialize.html) but in reality it doesn't really matter as long as the CA setting the property and the CA decoding the property follow the same spec.

Comment: Still In your website, I cannot find how to do it in C++. In C# it could be done with `session.CustomActionData["SomeKey"]`, but I don't know how to achieve the same in c++. Any idea?